# using AJAX to register an user name

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using ajax "POST" to register username and password in ruby server side. The code below is my ajax code.

```
$('#register-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var signup = {
        username: $('input[name="username"]').val(),
        password: $('input[name="password"]').val(),
        password_confirmation: $('input[name="confirm_password"]').val(),
        email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
        realname: $('input[name="realname"]').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "http://wwww.example.com/users",
        data: signup,
        success: function() {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('signup fail!');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But in my ruby server, I got an error. I can't figure out what wrong it is?

this is what my ruby server told me.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-26 11:45:56 -0700
Processing by UsersController#create as */*
Parameters: {"username"=>"jamme92", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"jamme@gmail.com", "realname"=>"hien luong 92"}←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('jamme92') LIMIT 1←[0m Rendered shared/error.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Any suggestion for what bug it is?

create function in users_controller

```
def create
response_initialize

user_potential = User.new
user_potential.from_params(params)
#user_potential.password_from_params(params)

if user_potential.save
  session_user = user_potential
  session_user.permissions_seed_default
else
  error_messages = "<p>Registration failed because:</p><ul>"
  user_potential.errors.full_messages.each do |error|
    error_messages = "#{error_messages}<li>#{error}</li>"
  end
  error_messages = "#{error_messages}</ul>"
  error_render(error_messages)
end
```

end

Here is what errors I got back from browser

Registration failed because:

Password can't be blank
Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
Password confirmation can't be blank

Comment: can you show us your `#create` action in your `users` controller?

Comment: I took off the filter_parameters for password, but the server still got error.

Comment: just a suggestion not sure it would help with your actual issue but rather than generating `html` in your controller why not respond with a `jSon` object and handle the dynamic generation in jQuery? Also instead of doing `error_messages = "#{error_messages}..."` you could simply do `error_messages << "..."` because `<<` will append to the string. Also adding your `user.from_params` method would probably be useful as this is probably where the issue is.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in dev env so you get full output of your logs? I want to see the stack trace where exception happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much you know about `ajax`, but there are two ways to achieve what you're looking for

Firstly, let me just say that one of the problems you have is that you're assigning `data` to your ajax call individually. You'll be much better placed to set a form & then either submit the form using the [Rails UJS driver](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), or by standard JQuery (like what you're trying to do)

Although this is not a major concern (your params are being sent), following either of the methods below will make sure the functionality is extensible:

--

**UJS**

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#form", function(){
   alert("success");
});
```

--

**Ajax**

To fix your code directly, you'll want to make use of the jquery [serialize();](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "#form", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "/users", 
      data: $(this).serialize();
      success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
      }
   });
});
```

---

**Controller**

Although this won't fix your issue directly - it will certainly help improve what you're trying to do. I'd personally look to get your flow as conventional as possible:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
    respond_to :js, :json, :html

    def create   
       @user = User.new user_params

       if user.save
         session_user = @user
         session_user.permissions_seed_default
       end

       #errors will be populated in your model
       respond_with @user
    end

    private

    def user_params
       params(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :realname)
    end
end
```

A caveat here is that I'm not sure how you're handling your `password` attributes. They're filtered, I believe, by the browser, so how you're saving them will be dependent on how they're processed in your controller

Comment: Thanks Rich, I found out that my variables in signup was not correct. My id in html was passcode and passcode_confirm, not password and password_confirmation.